# Rails inspecting status of parameters before save redundant element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following parameters are being submitted to a controller action for class `Cartitem`:

```
Parameters: {"cartitem"=>{"price_ordered"=>"0.99", "article_id"=>"1852", "quantity_ordered"=>"2,5"}, "button"=>""}
```

As some parameters need setting or sanitizing, i.e.

```
params[:cartitem][:quantity_ordered] = params[:cartitem][:quantity_ordered].sub(",", ".")
@article = Article.find(params[:cartitem][:article_id])
params[:cartitem][:price_um] = @article.price
```

in testing, the values are being intercepted with

```
puts params[:cartitem][:quantity_ordered]
puts params[:cartitem][:cart_id]
puts params.inspect
```

and returning

```
2.5
5
*[inspection broken down into multiple lines]*
#<ActionController::Parameters {"cartitem"=>#<ActionController::Parameters 
{"price_ordered"=>0.2475e1, "article_id"=>"1852",  
"quantity_ordered"=>"2.5", "price_um"=>0.99e0, "cart_id"=>5} permitted: false>, 
"button"=>"", "controller"=>"cartitems", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Now the action is failing because of a validation error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Cart must exist):
```

The oddity is that the params appear to be correct (cart_id not null, thus exists), but the result is different. Thus some alteration is occuring.

The inspection of the parameters reveals a curiosity where `ActionController::Parameters` and attributes like `permitted` is invoked twice.

Why are the parameters being handled in this manner and how can this be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

First off you should set this up as a proper nested resource. Move  the `cart_id` parameter into the path instead of the parameter:

```
resources :cart do
  resources :cartitems, only: :create
end
```

Change the form to submit to your new nested route:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@cart, @cartitem]) do |form| %>
```

Make sure you remove the `cart_id` hidden input.

Then setup a callback that will find the cart and raise a ActiveRecord::NotFoundException if its not found:

```
class CartitemsController < ApplicationRecord
  # ... 
  before_action :set_cart

 
  def create
    @cartitem = @cart.cartitems.new(cartitem_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:cart_id])
  end

  def cartitem_params
    params.require(:cartitem)
          .permit(
            :price_ordered, :article_id, :quantity_ordered
          )
  end
end
```

When it comes to that whole params conversion mess thats something which can be handled in the model layer. This is much easier and faster to test then monkeying around with the parameters in the controller:

```
class CartItem < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def quantity_ordered=(value)
    value.is_a?(String) ? super(value.sub(",", ".")) : super
  end
end
```

If you're doing something more advanced like for example supporting parameters for multiple versions of an API then move this to a separate object.

You also want to avoid:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:cartitem][:article_id])
```

As that will give a 404 if the item is not found which will be really unhelpful to the user. You instead want to handle this with a validation and a callback so that you can display an error message on the form instead.

Comment: On a side note the name `cartitems` should also really be `cart_items` .